# AS3 How to make a kind of array that index things based on a object? but not being strict like dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, indexing

How to make a kind of array that index things based on a object? but not being strict like dictionary.

What I mean:

```
var a:Object = {a:3};
var b:Object = {a:3};

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dict[a] = 'value for a';

// now I want to get the value for the last assignment
var value = dict[b];

// value doesn't exits :s
```

How to make something like that. TO not be to heavy as a lot of data will be flowing there.

I have an idea to use the toString() method but I would have to make custom classes.. I would like something fast..

Comment: Why do you need to store the key by object name?  A simple way would be to always store dict.last when you store dict[a].  So dict[a] = dict.last = somevalue;

Comment: Because in my project objects will have more than one attribute. So I need the object that have the same values as attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make a special class that encapsulates an array, put methods in there to add and remove elements from the array, and then you could make a special method (maybe getValueByObject(), whatever makes sense).  Then you could do:

```
var mySpecialArrayClass:MySpecialArrayClass = MySpecialArrayClass();

var a:Object = {a:3};
var b:Object = {a:3};

mySpecialArrayClass.addElement(a,'value for a');

var value = mySpecialArrayClass.getValueByObject(a);
```

I could probably cook up a simple example of such a class if you don't follow.

**Update:**

Would something like this help?

http://snipplr.com/view/6494/action-script-to-string-serialization-and-deserialization/

**Update:**

Could you use the === functionality?  if you say

```
if ( object === object )
```

it compares the underlying memory address to see if two objects are the same reference...

Comment: is what I'm currently do. I just override the toString() method and return a kind of serialized string. will be then indexed by that.. but i was wanting better ways.. or alternatives. the serialize  method currently is manual set for each object.

Comment: that would be good, but it seems lot heavy processing.. any lighter processes?

Comment: the problem is that is not important if is the same object. Only have to have the same properties and values. | in the example you wrote: "if(a === b)" will be false